# Differences in usage between する and やる

Tags: nuances, verbs

On the surface, many Japanese-English dictionaries define both する and やる as "to do", with little extra context.  Offhand, I know the following:

- やる and する are not interchangeable when it comes to する verbs (e.g. `× 死亡やる`)
- やる also has a number of additional senses along the lines of "to give", especially where the recipient is an inferior

Setting aside the second point for now, what's the 使い分け for the two words in the context of "to do"?

Comment: Yaru can sound rude, sometimes means something bad. やれ, やられた, 無理やり(the only adverb where やり is used instead of して).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that for some compounds using やり, it is not always replaceable with the compound using し, such as やり方 and やりくり.

Comment: どうやって⇔どうして　やり方⇔し方　無理やり⇔無理して　やった⇔(?)した　やらないか⇔しないか　やるね⇔(?)するね

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only やる is acceptable in some common phrases:

> - **やっ**た！I did it! ×した！
> - **やら**れた！You got me! ×された！
> - **やれ**、**やれ**！Go for it! ×しろ、しろ！
> - **やら**れたら**やり**返せ。Eye for an eye. ×されたらし返せ。
> - **やっ**てくる come along ×してくる
> - **やっ**ていく get along, make a living ×していく
> - **やっ**ちまえ！Get him! ×しちまえ！

やる is used/preferred for:

> - 何時まで**やっ**てますか？(≒営業する open; on business) ×何時までしてますか？
> - 演奏会でピアノを**やる**(≒演奏する perform) ×演奏会でピアノをする
> - 映画館でハリポタ**やっ**てる。(≒上映する is showing) △映画館でハリポタしてる。
> - 今(テレビで)何か**やっ**てる？(≒放送する broadcast) △今(テレビで)何かしてる？
> - 小学生から書道を**やっ**ています。(≒習う learn) △書道をしています。
> - [神社]{じんじゃ}で[陶器市]{とうきいち}を**やっ**ている。(≒[開催]{かいさい}する hold) △陶器市をしている。
> - [薬]{くすり・ヤク}/[麻薬]{まやく}/酒タバコを**やる** (on drugs, smoke and drink) ×薬/酒タバコをする
> - 俺は**やっ**てない！(≒殺す、犯罪を犯す murder/crime) △俺はしてない！
> - 携帯どこに**やっ**たっけ？Where did I put my phone? (≒置く) ×どこにしたっけ？
> - **やる**[気]{き} motivation ◎**やる**気あんのか!? ×する気あんのか!?

---

する is used in common phrases such as:

> - (colloquial)塩コショウを**する**。(≒かける sprinkle) ×塩コショウをやる。but ×砂糖をする/やる
> - どう**し**てですか？(≒なぜ why) ×どうやってですか？
> - **し**かた/**し**ょうがない。どう**し**ようもない。(It can't be helped) ×やりかたがない。△やりようがない。×どうやりようもない。
> - どう**し**たの？(What's wrong?) ×どうやったの？
> - どう**し**よう！(What should I do?) ×どうやろう？

You use する to say

> - あくびを**する**(yawn) くしゃみを**する**(sneeze) うがいを**する**(gargle) etc. ×あくび/くしゃみ/うがいをやる
> - 頭痛/[吐]{は}き[気]{け}/目まい/[匂]{にお}いが**する** (≒感じる feel, sense) ×頭痛/吐き気/匂いがやる
> - ネクタイ/ネックレス/[眼鏡]{めがね}etcを**する** (≒(アクセサリーなどを)[着]{つ}ける wear) ×ネクタイ/ネックレス/眼鏡をやる but ×帽子をする/やる
> - price+**する**(≒かかる cost) ◎10万円も**し**た。×10万円もやった。
> - noun+に**する**(≒選ぶ choose) ◎これに**し**ます。×これにやります。
> - verb+ことに**する**(≒決める decide) ◎行くことに**し**ます。×行くことにやります。
> - verb+ように**する**(be sure to) ◎遅れないように**し**てください。
> - ご飯に**し**ましょう。(≒始める start) ×ご飯にやりましょう。
> - お開きに**する**, 終りに**する** (≒終わらせる call it a night, to end) ×お開きにやる, 終りにやる

---

By the way, both する and やる are used in:

> - **し**て**やっ**たり！/（まんまと）**し**て**やら**れた！to fool, deceive ×してやる。×してやった。×してやろう。

Comment: Very helpful. Maybe we could add that する has an additional uses for expressions such as wear/sense/cost that do not apply to やる？：eg １）ネッくレスをする ２）においがする   ３）家賃が１０万円もする

Comment: 参考までに http://webnote.cocolog-nifty.com/note1/2013/06/post-135b.html とか　http://www.ninjal.ac.jp/event/specialists/project-meeting/files/JCLWorkshop_no4_papers/JCLWorkshop_No4_14.pdf する・やるの違いはたくさんあって、論文や本も書ける題材みたいです。

Answer (score 9):

The followings are some basic rules, although these are far from complete (a complete answer would be [very long](http://libir.soka.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10911/4040/1/nn24-y041.pdf)).

○ indicates correct and × indicates incorrect.

- やる is "to do" but you can use it only for *physical* activities you do *voluntarily* with a certain amount of time and effort.

  > - ○ テニスをする　○ テニスをやる
  > - ○ 想像をする　× 想像をやる (想像 is not a physical action)
  > - ○ あくびをする　× あくびをやる (あくび is not something you do voluntarily)
  > - ○ ジャンプをする　× ジャンプをやる (ジャンプ is a very short action)
- But there are many nouns which you cannot use やる with.

  > - ○ 電話をする　× 電話をやる
  > - ○ 旅行をする　× 旅行をやる
  > - ○ 約束をする　× 約束をやる
- やる cannot directly follow a noun.

  > - ○ 勉強する　○ 勉強をする　× 勉強やる　○ 勉強をやる
  > - ○ 仕事する　○ 仕事をする　× 仕事やる　○ 仕事をやる

  As for the difference between ～する and ～をする, see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3395/5010). (In reality, を before やる is sometimes omitted in a hasty conversation. Beginners should not do this.)
- When ～をする and ～をやる are interchangeable, ～をやる tends to sound colloquial and a bit masculine.
- Both やる and する have lots of idiomatic usages, as shown in the other answers. For example, only する can mean "wear" (e.g. 時計をする, ベルトをする), whereas やる has several argot-like, slangy usages ("to kill", "to have sex", "to smoke", etc).

So I would say する is the safer choice when you are unsure.

Answer (score -2):

It is difficult to distinguish the usage of them clearly.

But I think, generally, やる is informal, する is not informal (but not formal).

Of course it depends on the context, verb, etc.

Comment: I don't think this answer explains the difference very well. Can you expand it and provide some evidence, examples, etc.?