# やる in interviews and other polite contexts

Tags: politeness

## 日本語

この前、就職の面接で、この質問が頭に浮かんできました。普段しゃべるとき、私はよく「やる」とやるの活用を使っていますが、面接では「やる」より「する」や「します」の方が丁寧だと感じます。たまに「する」が使えませんが、その場合、「やる」を使ってもいいですか。そうでない場合、何と言うべきですか。

ちなみに、先に [Differences in usage between する and やる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/differences-in-usage-between-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%82%84%E3%82%8B) を見ましたが、私の質問には答えていないと思います。

言い換えると、以下のことを聞きたいです。

1. 「する」は「やる」より丁寧ですか。
2. 「やる」を別の表現で言い換えるのが難しい場合、面接で使えますか。
3. （必要に応じて）「やる」の代わりに何が使えますか。

## English

Earlier during a job interview, this question came to mind. Often when I speak in Japanese, I use "yaru" and its variations conjugations, but my impression is that it's not as polite as "suru" or "shimasu." Also there are some cases where "suru" cannot be substituted in, in such cases is it acceptable to use "yaru"? If not, what should one use?

By the way, I looked at [Differences in usage between する and やる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/differences-in-usage-between-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%82%84%E3%82%8B) but it doesn't appear to be answering my question.

In short, my question is as follows:

1. Is "suru" more polite than "yaru"?
2. when there's no easy alternative to "yaru" can it be used in an interview?
3. what are some practical alternatives to saying "yaru" (should this be necessary)?

Comment: I think you should give examples.

Comment: That's a good point ... I'll try to think of some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

両方使えるとき「する」が「やる」より丁寧だとは必ずしも言えません。また、具体的にそういう例がよくあるわけではありません。

例えば、「ある仕事を決断し実行する」という意味では、ふつう「やる」を使います。

- やりたい仕事
- やるべき時にやる
- 『すぐやる課』

こういうときに「する」のほうが丁寧だと思い込んで「やる」を使うのは良くないと考えるのは過剰修正です。

なので、あまり気にしなくていいと思います。

Comment: This definitely helps because these are examples close to what I ended up using "やる気"など。

Answer (score 1):

> １．「する」は「やる」より丁寧ですか。

「する」自身は普通の表現であって丁寧な表現ではないですが、「やる」に比べれば相対的に丁寧です。逆に言いますと、「する」と言えるときに「やる」というのは明らかに粗野な表現です。

> ２．「やる」を別の表現で言い換えるのが難しい場合、面接で使えますか。

どのような時を難しい場合と言っているか分かりませんが、次のような２つの状況を想定して回答します。

(1) [Differences in usage between する and やる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/differences-in-usage-between-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%82%84%E3%82%8B) の中に、「する」ではなく「やる」としか表現できない場合は、「やる」を使うのが普通の表現ですので、面接でもそのまま使えます。
(2) 本来「する」を使うべき時に、面接時の緊張からうっかり「やる」と言った場合には、あなたが日本人でないことは明白でしょうから、言い換えれば良いでしょう。もし、面接官と打ち解けた話ができる状況であれば、あなたが今まで「する」と「やる」の使い分けでどんなにたくさん勉強してきたかを披露し、それでも使い分けが難しく間違うことがあると伝えるのも一つの方法です。更に打ち解けているのなら「やっちゃった！」と「やる」を使った表現で愛嬌を振りまいてその場をしのいでください。

> ３．（必要に応じて）「やる」の代わりに何が使えますか。

実際に何が言いたいのか、あるいは、文脈に依存しますので、具体的に必要な状況を含めて質問してください。そのとき、適切な回答ができると思います。

Comment: 「するといえる時にやるというのは明らかに粗野な表現です」とのことですが、具体的にどういう例がありますか？「するとやるが両方使えるときはやるが必ず粗野になる」ということですか？

Comment: @user4092: 必ずかどうかは証明が大変難しい質問ですが、具体的な例として「私がする。」「私がやる。」を比較すると簡単にわかるように思います。

Comment: 後段についてはどうですか？ 私はそうは思いませんが。

Comment: @user4092: 「後段」ってなんですか？

Comment: 私が問題だと思うのは両方可能だが「やる」が適切な場合まで「する」を使うのは過剰修正だということです。

Comment: @user4092: 「後段」、両方可能だが「やる」が適切な場合 のいずれも具体例がないので理解できませんが、両方可能だが「やる」が適切な場合があるなら、それは論理的に「やる」を使うのが適切なのでしょう。いずれにせよ具体例でもって教えていただければありがたいです。

Comment: 失礼しました。私の解答で取り上げた「何かを決断し実行する」場合がその事例に当ります。

Comment: @user4092: 昨日あなたの回答を見て、なるほどと思いました。「後段」っていうのは、回答が画面上の下の方にあるという意味かなとも推察しました。回答に触発されて「やる」を少し調べることができました。的は絞りにくいですが、質問者の方へ有効な情報を差し上げられるように、現在追加情報をまとめております。掲載した折にはまたご意見いただければと思います。大変勉強になっております。