# What is the difference between を　vs　の in 何を勉強します　and　何の勉強します?

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-を

What is the difference between を　vs　の  in  何を勉強します　and　何の勉強します ?

I noticed in sentences both variants. And I wonder which of them more properly or in which case they are should be used?

P.S.Neither english nor japanese are native languages ​​for me.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/can-a-noun-suru-have-an-adjective-modify-the-noun-as-well

Comment: I think the link above actually not related to this topic (question).

Comment: The link says that 何の勉強する is ungrammatical.